# Need help to make a customEditMode as Environment

Tags: swift, swiftui

I like to re-build a customEditMode like same editMode in SwiftUI for learning purpose, I could made my code until a full error codes as possible, that was not my plan! However here is what I tried until now, need help to get this codes work. thanks

**Update:**

Why this Circle color does not change?

```
    struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.customEditMode) var customEditMode
    
    var body: some View {

        CircleView()
        
        VStack {
            
            Button("active") { customEditMode?.wrappedValue = CustomEditMode.active }.padding()

            Button("inactive") { customEditMode?.wrappedValue = CustomEditMode.inactive }.padding()

            Button("none") { customEditMode?.wrappedValue = CustomEditMode.none }.padding()
            
        }
        .onChange(of: customEditMode?.wrappedValue) { newValue in
            
            if newValue == CustomEditMode.active {
                
                print("customEditMode is active!")
            }
            else if newValue == CustomEditMode.inactive {
                
                print("customEditMode is inactive!")
            }
            else if newValue == CustomEditMode.none {
                
                print("customEditMode is none!")
            }
 
        }

    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.customEditMode) var customEditMode
    
    var body: some View {

        Circle()
            .fill(customEditMode?.wrappedValue == CustomEditMode.active ? Color.green : Color.red)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the `editMode`:

```
@available(macOS, unavailable)
@available(watchOS, unavailable)
public var editMode: Binding<EditMode>?
```

you can see that it is in fact a `Binding`. That's why you access its value using `wrappedValue`.

You need to do the same for your `CustomEditModeEnvironmentKey`:

```
enum CustomEditMode {
    case active, inactive, none

    // optionally, if you need mapping to `Bool?`
    var boolValue: Bool? {
        switch self {
        case .active: return true
        case .inactive: return false
        case .none: return nil
        }
    }
}

struct CustomEditModeEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Binding<CustomEditMode>? = .constant(.none)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var customEditMode: Binding<CustomEditMode>? {
        get { self[CustomEditModeEnvironmentKey] }
        set { self[CustomEditModeEnvironmentKey] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Here is a demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var customEditMode = CustomEditMode.none

    var body: some View {
        TestView()
            .environment(\.customEditMode, $customEditMode)
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.customEditMode) var customEditMode

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(customEditMode?.wrappedValue == .active ? Color.green : Color.red)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
        VStack {
            Button("active") { customEditMode?.wrappedValue = .active }.padding()
            Button("inactive") { customEditMode?.wrappedValue = .inactive }.padding()
            Button("none") { customEditMode?.wrappedValue = .none }.padding()
        }
        .onChange(of: customEditMode?.wrappedValue) { newValue in
            print(String(describing: newValue))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I wanted to cover Equatable problem in CustomEditMode, that is why I used Bool? in my enum, with your answer, I got one question left over, where and how I should import  Equatable protocol to CustomEditMode? thanks

Comment: @swiftPunk You need to use `customEditMode?.wrappedValue` in `onChange`. I updated my answer and added a demo.

Comment: I just can't wrap my head around this topic! It is getting difficult! the way you just coded like in your demo is kind of EnvironmentObject which you are suppling assister view, like you done for TestView, the all point of trying to use and customise  an Environment like customEditMode, was getting rid of suppling views, for example we do not supplies colorScheme or scenePhase, we just access them, I updated my code with help of your code but still not working what I was hoping, see me code in up please, I know it is nasty coding situation but I like to learn it and understand it.

Comment: @swiftPunk *we do not supplies colorScheme or scenePhase* - but we don't *change* them as well. The reason why the value is not changing if you don't inject it to the environment is that I used a *constant* binding: `static let defaultValue: Binding<CustomEditMode>? = .constant(.none)`. Instead it could be `static let defaultValue: Binding<CustomEditMode>? = .init(get: { customEditMode }, set: { customEditMode = $0 })` with `static private var customEditMode = CustomEditMode.none`. But this won't refresh the view as the binding remains the same - you need a `State` for that.

Comment: I completely understand what is your goal to tell me about "but we don't change them as well"  If you mean of changing, is updating that with those 3 Button`s, I have to tell you that does not count as changing! Let me explain: when we use colorScheme we can not update it, that is right because it is a get! But we can manually change our app style to dark mode or light mode, that does count as changing for colorScheme right? Since I am in first steps of discovering customEditMode I can not and I do not know right now to give a set and get possibility to customEditMode, that is why

Comment: that is why I am updating customEditMode with those 3 Buttons! I mean you are right but also I am right! It is hard to explain.

Comment: @swiftPunk When you set the colorScheme, you inject `.environment(\.colorScheme, .light)` at the root of the environment you want to have this specific colorScheme. The same is with `.environment(\.customEditMode, $customEditMode)` in the above answer. As far as I know you can only add a set option through another `@State`/`@Binding` properties, so you inject them to the environment.